# Oracle SQL Developer - Missing right parenthesis when trying to view tables from hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The title says it all, really - I'm connected to my University's oracle server through a VPN and I am trying to view the tables of another user through the hierarchy pane on the left, but I am recieving the error:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Vendor code 907
```

This is only from trying to expand the 'Tables (filtered)' folder under the 'Other Users' folder.

I also get this error when trying to view my own 'Tables (filtered)' folder.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Edit: I should probably clarify that all other functionality I have tried to use is working just fine, I can create and view tables through pure SQL.

Comment: ?  read the question again mike, this is with the viewer, no sql to show.  @Nathan Can you see any tables from any user?  There are a couple potential causes...Almost tempted to say download TOAD and see if it can see the tables.

Comment: Nope, I can't seem to view any tables from any users - including myself.

Comment: Download another viewer and see if it gets the same error.  If it doesn't, then something is messed with your oracle developer install and I'd reinstall.  If it does, then my guesses are at permissions or a ddl trigger (but those are guesses).  I realize this isn't much of an answer, but troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Might I ask what clients you'd recommend? The only SQL I've done prior to this module is barebones stuff in PHP.

Comment: Oracle?  I'd use TOAD (Tool for Oracle App Developers) as my first choice (free online, and rather robust when it comes to it).

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you using? Do you have any filters on the table view?